# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader to Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader

Tags: c#

I'm receiving the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'
>   to 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
{
    string query = "select * from Sales.Store";
    SqlConnection readerconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2000;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand readercmd = new SqlCommand(query);

    try
    {
        readerconn.Open();
        readercmd = readerconn.CreateCommand();
        readercmd.CommandText = query;
        readercmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader TestReader = readercmd.ExecuteReader();

        return TestReader; //Getting error at this line

        readerconn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

After modifying the code as per the Radin Gospodinov suggestion, i am not getting the error but i am unable to get the data into the dataset.Here is the modified code

```
public class MySqlDataReader:Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader
        {
            private System.Data.IDataReader sourceDataReader;
            private System.Data.DataTable dt;
            private System.Data.DataSet ds;
            public MySqlDataReader(System.Data.IDataReader datareader)
            {
                this.sourceDataReader = datareader;
            }

            public MySqlDataReader(System.Data.DataTable dt)
            {
                // TODO: Complete member initialization
                this.dt = dt;
            }

            public MySqlDataReader(System.Data.DataSet ds)
            {
                // TODO: Complete member initialization
                this.ds = ds;
             }
public IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
        {
            string query = "select * from Sales.Store";
            SqlConnection readerconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IE11DT4RJC6Q1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2000;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            SqlCommand readercmd = new SqlCommand(query);

            try
            {
                readerconn.Open();
                readercmd = readerconn.CreateCommand();
                readercmd.CommandText = query;
                readercmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataReader TestReader = readercmd.ExecuteReader();
                //TestReader.Close();
                readerconn.Close();
                //readerconn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query,readerconn);
                adapter.SelectCommand = readercmd;
                System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "result");
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                readerconn.Close();
                return new MySqlDataReader(ds);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlDataReader implements System.Data.IDataReader, so if you want to cast to IDataRader you should use `public System.Data.IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)`
Also close the connection in finally block:

```
try
{
  readerconn.Open()
}
catch{...}
finally
{
  readerconn.Close();
}
```

If you want to use Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader then you should create a class that implements this and pass SqlDataReader to it:

```
public class MySqlDataReaderWrapper:
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader
    {
      private System.Data.IDataReader sourceDataReader;
      public MySqlDataReaderWrapper(System.Data.IDataReader dataReader)
      {
        this.sourceDataReader = dataReader.
      }
    // Implementation of methods of Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader
    }
```

then in your method use `return new MySqlDataReaderWrapper(testDataReader);`

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, i have done what you have suggested,but i am unable to get the data. once check the code please. i edited my question once check in there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed namespaces. You're looking for [`System.Data.IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Data;
```

And add a reference to that assembly, and if not needed remove `Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing`.

Comment: i am looking for Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader

Comment: But `SqlDataReader` doesn't implement it. It implements `System.Data.IDataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a `Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader`, I'm assuming not, which suggests in your using statements you've got a reference to some of ReportingServices with its implementation of `IDataReader`.

So you could remove that reference, or fully qualify the `IDataReader` in the method i.e. `public System.Data.IDataReader ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)`

Comment: yes, i want Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDataReader not System.Data.IDataReader